# How can I attach the sill plate to the block formation (contractor did not do it)

Tags: anchor

When we purchased this home we had some renovations done before we moved in, one included framing in an existing covered porch on 2 sides. The builder came highly recommended and routinely built $500k+ homes and received numerous awards for homes in the area. He was originally going to build our home from scratch but issues with the land eventually led us to find a great home built in 2000. The builder seemed to be the most knowledgeable about what we wanted to do, was not the cheapest of the quotes we received, (*we met some characters*), and was professional in all our dealings.

When construction started they went under the deck, dug a trench and had a footer poured, then a block mason added a cinder block support wall on the 2 outside walls, so I felt pretty comfortable in the way they were progressing.

Fast forward 5 years, I'm in the process of becoming a home inspector and I started noticing things. We had him open up several interior walls, beams were added but the support columns were not tied into the beam below causing the floor to bounce. This made me want to take a close look at the addition, today I went under and looked around, as far as I can tell there are no bolts holding down the sill plate, the center support beam not touching the 2 support columns, and only a few of the floor joists are nailed to it, and the blocks were not back filled. I am planning to shim and add clamps to the center support beam.

**Question:** How can I attach the exterior wall to the foundation?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the clearance, use a hammer drill with a masonry percussion bit to drill down through the sill plate into the concrete block.  Then use a two-part anchoring epoxy to embed galvanized bolts through the sill plate into the epoxy filled hole.  After the epoxy cures, add galvanized washer, or washer plate, bolt, and tighten down.

You also might be able to use a strap tie, that fastens to a wall stud and the foundation.  Something like this one (from Simpson):

[image]

Comment: I appreciate the reply, everything is finished so I could not tie the straps into the studs there is also a deck on the outside even if I removed the cement board siding. Could I run straps from the floor joists to the blocks? I can probably get an angle drill in and drill holes to place bolts because none of the blocks were backfilled with concrete, is there another product that could be poured into the voids that would add strength and set the bolt?

Answer (score 0):

My brother is an ex-inspector and GC - has actually built over 500 homes and inspected many thousands of homes in his career. I had him inspect a home in an exclusive development in Salem, SC that we had a contract on. Had a 12" block foundation wall (up to 10' high in some points). Was neither filled nor reinforced, sill plate simply resting on the wall, no anchors. We walked away from the contract as my brother said while it was technically feasible to build an interior structural steel frame and secure the walls and sill, he said it was a six figure job and few people could do it correctly such that it would work. I'm finding out that several other homes that were built in this same subdivision also simply have the house sill plate resting on the block wall foundation, with nothing anchoring the house down. Caveat emptor..